# Communication between Windows phone and a desktop application

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-8, desktop-application

I want to have a WPF application running on my desktop to communicate with the windows phone. For instance my WPF application should bring all the contacts/messages from Windows phone to local disk. Then I have to store it somehow. But it is the data fetching part which I have to go through first.

Phone would be connected to PC via USB cable. Is there any library available for c# which can give me methods to extract such phone specific data when phone is USB-connected to the PC?

Comment: You cannot do this through an external API. You can access contacts from with an app